# string to date convert C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I like to convert the string "May 01 2000" into DateTime

I tried this code below but I get an error

```
string date = "May 01 2000";
DateTime DT=Convert.ToDateTime(date)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string s = "May 01 2000";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But, you are **almost always** better off using [`DateTime.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) since it won't throw an exception if the conversion fails:

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent and returns a value that **indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded.**

```
string s = "May 01 2000";
DateTime dateValue;

if (DateTime.TryParse(s, out dateValue) == true)
{
    // succeeded ...
}
```

Comment: hi @mitch what ic the string is like this "Mon May 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0800"?

Comment: is that the same question?  I'm not sure that's a standard format?